# IIS is slow when visiting a localhost site that has a domain name assigned?

Tags: asp.net, iis, dns

I have an asp.net application running quite well on "localhost/mysite/webapp/"

I decided to use ASP.net routing so to match product which will be "mysite.com/", I assigned a domain name to the website being "mysite.local" and now i can access it via mysite.local on the brower. I have added the relevant 127.0.0.1 entry in the 'hosts' file.

When i access a simple asp.net page that is mainly text (for example a terms and conditions page) from localhost/mysite/webapp/terms.aspx it loads in about 100ms when i access the same page on mysite.local/terms.aspx it load in at least 4500ms and it seems that there is about a 4.5 seconds delay on every other request using mysite.local/terms.aspx.

I'm guessing this is happening because the machine is trying to determine whether this is a website that exists elsewhere so it goes through DNS but why wouldn't just pick it up from the hosts file and load it exactly like it's loading localhost?

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Hosts file should not be the culprit. What is the routing rules you use?

Comment: after further invistigation, it seems that the problem is with the underlying layers and nothing to do with .net. If i ping localhost, i get the response instantly but if i ping mysite.local it takes about 4 seconds and then i get the response. So it has to be in the networking level??